# Bootstrap Form Is Not Responsive In Mobile

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a landing page that looks fine on a desktop, but horrible in mobile. The form goes outside of the background image and creates a lot of white space. Is there a way to make the form stay inside of the background image?

Thanks!

Here is a link and code snippet: crimsonroot.com/files/php/gettr.php

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12 center">    

            <form>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name"/>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>

                </div>

                <button id="goGettr" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Make Me A Go Gettr!</button>

            </form>

</div>
```

Comment: It actually looks completely fine on my phone. Not sure what to tell you. Looks good when I re-size the browser as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `.container` class to this:

```
.container {
background-attachment: fixed; /* modified here */
background-image: url("gettrbackground.jpeg");
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
min-height: 100%; /* modified here */
padding-top: 100px;
width: 100%;
}
```